# $_POST and static variables

Tags: class, post, static

I am trying to ensure that I only instantiate a class once. In my function I have a static variable.  When $_POST receives a value, it calls the function with the value received.  Why is this static variable overwritten each time? $aClass is always NULL.  Is the $_POST call via HTML resetting everything?

```
function RunFunctions($inputStr)
{
    static $aClass;
    var_dump($aClass);

    if (!isset($aClass))
    {
        $aClass = new CreateNewClass();
        $aClass->SetNumber($inputStr); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us full details on your PHP setup, but most PHP environments are start-from-scratch on each request. What this means is that the entire program is initialized from scratch including your static variables each time.

If you're not using an optimizer, the PHP code itself can be compiled from scratch for each request as well.

A lot of PHP requests are handled by separate system processes, meaning that even if data could be shared between requests, it would only work for requests handled by the same process.

If you want to share data between requests, consider storing it in a Cookie that the user's browser automatically provides on each request, or store it in a local database.

Comment: Thank you. That was my impression as well.  I even defined the class to be static and it too was re-initialised each time.  I was thinking along the same lines as you suggest in order to create a 'permanent' variable.